# Удалить из текста поста известные ссылки

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт с 40к записями, среди этих записей есть 7к записей, в которых есть внешние ссылки, мне их нужно удалить.

Здесь я нашел уже подобный вопрос и ответ на него, но мне он не совсем подходит.

Вот код функции, который удаляет внешние ссылки из массива постов, в которых ссылки надо удалить.

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

function links_remove () {

    $links_mass = json_decode(file_get_contents('exlinks.json')); //массив известных внешних ссылок, которые надо удалить
    $allurl = json_decode(file_get_contents('links.json')); //массив ссылок на записи, в которых есть внешние ссылки

    foreach((array) $allurl as $jurl) {

        $id = url_to_postid($jurl);

        $post = get_post($id);
        $content = $post->post_content;
        $html = str_get_html($content);
        foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
            foreach($links_mass as $link) {
                if (strpos($element->href, $link) !== false) {
                    $element->outertext = $element->innertext;
                }
            }
        }
        $post->post_content = (string) $html->save();
        wp_update_post( $post );
   } 
}
add_action ('init', 'links_remove');
```

Проблема в том, что весь контент записей сохранен без HTML тегов и при использовании этой функции текст в записи сохраняется в одну строчку т.е. удаляются абзацы.

Например:
**Было**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dignissim consectetur ex, sed feugiat nisl sodales vel. Nam pellentesque, elit vel laoreet sodales, magna ipsum condimentum nibh, quis laoreet erat libero et nunc.

Aliquam porttitor lectus sed tortor finibus, at congue orci pellentesque. Vivamus sit amet turpis tellus. Praesent efficitur in ante molestie molestie. 

Aliquam interdum lectus pharetra lacus mattis, ac viverra diam tempor. Nunc congue mollis finibus. Phasellus feugiat diam varius varius maximus. Etiam non nunc eros. Quisque sodales eros nec aliquam maximus. Phasellus a viverra mi.

Источник: <a href="http://#">Название сайта</a>
```

**Стало**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dignissim consectetur ex, sed feugiat nisl sodales vel. Nam pellentesque, elit vel laoreet sodales, magna ipsum condimentum nibh, quis laoreet erat libero et nunc.Aliquam porttitor lectus sed tortor finibus, at congue orci pellentesque. Vivamus sit amet turpis tellus. Praesent efficitur in ante molestie molestie.Aliquam interdum lectus pharetra lacus mattis, ac viverra diam tempor. Nunc congue mollis finibus. Phasellus feugiat diam varius varius maximus. Etiam non nunc eros. Quisque sodales eros nec aliquam maximus. Phasellus a viverra mi.Источник: Название сайта
```

Как сделать, чтобы при обновлении записи сохранялись абзацы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Текст постов в базе хранится с разделителями "\n". Они игнорируются simple html dom. Чтобы преобразовать контент из базы в html, используйте `wpautop()`:

```php
$content = wpautop( $post->post_content );
```

Comment: Спасибо, а можно как то сделать проверку на изменение контента записи?

Сейчас при каждой итерации запись обновляется, даже если контент не изменился, не очень хочется в пустую тратить ресурсы сервера на обновление не измененной записи.

Comment: Я только сейчас заметил, что у вас код работает на `init`. Т.е. при каждой загрузке страницы читаются тысячи постов. Это ужасно. Вам надо использовать хуки `save_post` и `post_updated`. Тогда вы сможете убирать ссылки только из того поста, что подвергается изменениям. Можно показать, как, но это тема для отдельного вопроса.

Comment: Задал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1500157/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) по этой теме, можете посмотреть?